# using xbox 360 wireless controller in MoveIt/ rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to jog an industrial 6-axis robot in rviz via a xbox 360 wireless controller.

I have created a MoveIt package as described [here](http://aeswiki.datasys.swri.edu/rositraining/indigo/Exercises/3.3) and started the demo.launch. Next, I followed [these](http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/indigo/api/moveit_ros_visualization/html/_sources/doc/joystick.txt) instruction to start the joystick_control.launch.

Although I have installed the latest ros-indigo-moveit-full I get the error

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [moveit_ros_visualization/moveit_joy.py]: can't locate node [moveit_joy.py] in package [moveit_ros_visualization]
```

How can fix that error?

Thanks a lot,
kr
RockOn

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223365/using-xbox-360-wireless-controller-in-moveit/-rviz/) by [RockOn_23](https://answers.ros.org/users/25322/rockon_23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2016-01-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-02**:
Your new error looks significantly different from the original problem. I'd suggest that you ask a new question instead of updating this one; that way, if someone comes along with a similar question, they'll find a simple answer.

**Comment by [RockOn_23](https://answers.ros.org/users/25322/rockon_23/) on 2016-01-02**:
ok, thanks :-)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-02**:
Reverted back to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like moveit_joy.py isn't included in the Ubuntu binaries for MoveIt

There was [a patch](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/pull/584) submitted to MoveIt to fix this about six months back, but there hasn't been a release since then, so that fix hasn't made it to binaries.

It looks like the MoveIt community is in the process of trying to release a new version: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_core/issues/270

Until then, you should be able to get around your issue by using MoveIt from source.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-02**:
Note though that `moveit_joy.py` does not allow you to jog the robot directly, but exposes a joystick interface to the *interactive markers* the MoveIt RViz plugin uses to configure the start and goal targets. This is rather different from how you'd normally jog an industrial robot.